# Following which database design have less cost for SQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, rdbms

Suppose I have a website and for its database there is one table is

Table_name table_1 and attributes are like table_1(a1(primary key,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7) and in my website for for most of transactions I only uses attributes (a1,a2,a3) but the a4,a5 ,a6 and a7 are rarely used so I want to know what is better design approach to access data from following option

A)keep this table as it is and use  this query select a1,a2,a3 from table_1;

B) Create 2 separate  table  table1(a1,a2,a3) and table_2(a1,a4,a5,a6,a7)

which approch have lower cost or load on database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For read querys over (a1, a2, a3), obviusly "b" is (not noticeably) cheaper.

But all the other things are worst **except** if (a4, a5, a6, a7) are, in most of cases, nulls and you used (1->0,1) cardinality between both tables (that is: for each a1 in table_1 there is 0 or 1 tuples with the same value of a1 in table_2 and, of course, all values of a1 in table_2 exists in table_1).

Anyway, as I said, any possible advantage will be minimal compared to the complexity, maintainability issues, and also efficiency reduction (for inserts and when you need data from both tables).

So, if I were you, I would select "a" layout without any doubt.

Answer (score 1):

B is provide less cost  than A . Because if you choose A option you'll have been wasted space for a4, a5, a6,a7. But if you choose B option, you must create a foreign key (a1) for connect table_1. And your SQL query become cheap.

Comment: Not as much for modern RDBMS. Nulls are handled very well and fixed length text or binary files are nowadays discouraged. Actually, in many cases is recommended to avoid them. For example, in PostgreSQL *text* is more recommended than *char* or *varchar* (even with no length limit varchar) and is supposed to be more efficient.